# Autolayout constraint conditional

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, ios-autolayout

I have a view and I add a subview to this with the following Autolayout requirements:

1. If view width is greater than or equal to view height, then i want subview width to be 75% of view width and height to be 15 points,
2. If view width is less than view height, then I want subview width to be fixed 15 points and subview height to be equal to 75% of view height.

How do I express these constraints programatically.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed, how to express the autolayout constraint that is conditional upon view.bounds.width/view.bounds.height.